# Bulk OS installation in a computer lab

Tags: installation, remote-control

I need some advice on which software should I use to perform bulk and remote operating system installation (ie, copying OS images) in a computer lab.

I have 3 labs with 30 identical workstations each. How could I remotely deploy an OS into all of them?

In addition, eventualy I have to install new software packages or updates.

Do you guys know any tool to support me in this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it *have* to be remotely?

Comment: Yep. It would help a lot. But any advices are welcome.

Comment: I've got no experience deploying remotely, which is why I asked. But anyway, I would probably clone the HDDs OR burn a stack of streamlimed bootable DVDs/USBs and see how closely I can get them all to finish at the same time. It all depends on how much time/money you want to spend on this project.

Comment: You can setup Automated installs in a lot of OSes. For example you could PXE boot a Debian install which then get's all of it's options from a preseed file. All you would need to do is turn the computer on,  tell it to boot from the network, then it will grab the install files and install itself quietly. There is something similar for Windows too but I forget what it's called.

Comment: What OS and what budget?

Comment: Thanks for your help, people. @AthomSfere: Windows with a severely constrained budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I help out a few places that do this about once a year, and currently we use Fog Project for this stuff (http://www.fogproject.org/) but it is really outdated and needing help. We are considering moving to a VMWare based PXE environment, that also may help you out, to do the job.

Hope this helps :)

PS. Multicast on FOG is pretty buggy if you're doing it on a bigger network, so if you go that route, stick either with single casting, or isolating the the clients/server from the rest of the network at time of multicast.

Comment: Nice tip! Fog looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

This will be OS dependent to some degree, but invariably you will want some kind of a PXE (Network Booting) startup.

If you are using a Linux based OS (I think there is some Windows support as well), you may want to run something like Puppet or Chef to allow you to control upgrades etc.

Realistically a lot more information is required to tease out a solution - for example, preferred OS, authentication mechanisms and access controls, skill level, hardware to be deployed.   I'd put to you this is not really a "Superuser" question as its to broad.

Comment: Actually, there are no much requirements for now. Some additional details: The workstations will run Windows 8 x64. Thanks.

Comment: I just found out that there's a SE site for software recommendations. :)